# How to make solver work in Excel [PlayOnLinux install]

Tags: playonlinux, microsoft-office

Because for school I have to work with Excel, I installed Microsoft office 2010 with PlayOnLinux. Office is working great, except when I try to use the solver function in Excel. The moment I activate solver, Excel simply shuts down. When I restart Excel, it comes up with the following message:

`Excel experienced a serious problem with the 'solver add-in' add-in. If you have seen this message multiple times, you should disable this add-in and check to see if an update is available. Do you want to disable this add-in?`

Comment: Well, first of all, follow that tip and check if there is an update for this add-in ;-).

Answer (score 1):

**You can solve your equation with [Wolfram|Alpha (click here - online service)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/)**: insert the equation and it will solve.
**You can also install Windows & Office in (example) [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and use them from here**: they will function for sure in this virtualized enviroment, you only need extra resources.

The Ubuntu community can only offer support for [Open Source](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) software and Microsoft® Office® 2010 is [Closed Source](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_source); playonlinux only offers a compatibility layer to execute Windows software but it can't do miracles if the source code is not public.
You should open a ticket in the [Microsoft® support center](http://support.microsoft.com) and ask why the plug-in causes a crash in compatibility enviroments.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

It seems working with macros and solver in Excel has many times compatibility problems. Therefore, you can

1. either install excel in virtual machine within Ubuntu, for example using [virtual box](https://www.virtualbox.org/)
2. or use libre-office calc [solver](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Solver)